# show / hide the element by using v-show attributes in Vue js

Tags: vue.js

Here my myVueInstance having two radio button and one text box. Based on click radio button options I should show / hide the text box.

```
<div id='myVueInstance'>

    <label>Show Text box or not ? </label>
    <input type="radio" id="one" value="true" v-model="picked">
        <label for="one">Yes</label>

        <input type="radio" id="two" value="false" v-model="picked" >
        <label for="two">No</label>
        <br>
        <span>Picked: {{ picked }}</span>
        <input  type='text' v-show='picked'> 

    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = new Vue({
        el:'#myVueInstance',
        data:{

            title : 'My learning of Vue',
            picked:true
        }
     });
</script>
```

Note : I'm using Vue updated version.

Answer (score 2):

Here, type of `picked` is becoming `String` when selecting radio button. Try this:

```js
 <input  type='text' v-show="picked === 'true'">
...
...
...
 data:{
   title : 'My learning of Vue',
   picked: 'true'
 }
```

Comment: Thank you @Sajib Khan for your quick attention on this. I got the solution by adding v-show="picked === 'true'" on my text box. Great !.

Comment: And Sajib, If you are set picked: true instead of picked: 'true'. Then you no need to check that data types like v-show="picked === 'true'". Instead of that you can check like v-show="picked ==true". :)

Comment: `===` is recommended, cause when we use `==` type conversion happens! :)

Comment: Yes so that I suggested as no need to pass as string type in el, as well as we no need to check ===. So if you are passed are string type in el, then we should check the type conversion also :) .

Comment: perfect, Helped me.